Does the pre-Laryngeal Brugmannian synthesis of PIE fully explain attested non-Anatolian data?
Was there a speech community that had lost most of the Laryngeals and spoke a language represented by Brugmann's reconstruction of PIE?

No, it does not explain.

What are some examples of say Latin or Greek data that the Brugmann system doesn't explain. but are explained through Laryngeals? @anixx

Draconis' answer highlights the main argument that historically led to the development of the laryngeal theory.
I don't believe this actually answers the question though, as this data can also be explained in non-laryngeal PIE by positing alternative ablaut paradigms (and some slightly more complicated phonotactic rules).
As such, looking only at ablaut data, we cannot justify reconstructing laryngeals at the Proto-Indo-European stage, but only at the Pre-Proto-Indo-European stage (or if we adopt an Indo-Anatolian perspective, at the Proto-Indo-Anatolian perspective).
That said, there are good arguments for reconstructing laryngeals at the Proto-Indo-European stage. These generally rely on less obvious effects than the unusual ablaut caused by laryngeals, and so only came to be recognised and properly understood after the laryngeal theory had already been accepted.

The first comes from looking at the vocalised laryngeals. In almost all branches, all vocalised laryngeals have the exact same reflex and so were reconstructed in Brugmannian Proto-Indo-European as a single phoneme *ə (the so-called Schwa Indogermanicum).
The problem is that this phoneme has an unpredictable triple reflex in Greek, either e, a, or o.
Adopting the laryngeal theory, we see that this reflex is predicted by the type of laryngeal that was vocalised: *h₁ gives e, *h₂ gives a, and *h₃ gives o.
This can be worked around by using an updated non-laryngeal reconstruction of Proto-Indo-European with three Schwas Indogermanica *ə₁, *ə₂, and *ə₃ however.
More damning for a non-laryngeal explanation of the non-Anatolian data is the Greek triple reflex of the "long" syllabic resonants.
Most branches distinguish between "short" and "long" syllabic resonants (that we now know correspond to a syllabic resonant imemdiately followed by a laryngeal in the same syllable). This is not itself a problem for Brugmannian Proto-Indo-European, however as with the Schwa Indogermanicum Greek poses a problem, as the long syllabic resonants *R̥̄ again have an unpredictable triple reflex as Rē, Rā (> Rē in Ionic), or Rō.
In a laryngeal context, the reflex is predictable, based on the type of following laryngeal, to try to accommodate it into a theory without laryngeals (and noting that these outcomes are distinct from what we'd expect the outcome of a non-syllabic resonant followed by one of our three schwas to be) we would have to posit something like three different types of long syllabic resonant (maybe: *R̥̄, R̥̄ˤ, R̥̄ʷ), but distinguishing secondary articulations like this without paralels in the non-syllabic resonants does not seem plausible.
As such we must accept that laryngeals were preserved (and distinctly) in Proto-Indo-European, even without resorting to Anatolian evidence, although possibly only when vocalised or adjacent to a sylalbic resonant.

There are also some less universally accepted pieces of evidence that require us to reconstruct laryngeals at the Proto-Indo-European stage if we accept them.
The best accepted of these is probably Cowgill's Law whereby *h₃w (and possibly *h₂w) become *kw in Proto-Germanic. As this change is definitely absent in other branches it would require that the laryngeals be preserved in Proto-Indo-European.
The existence of an *h₄ that colours vowels like *h₂ but is preserved as h in Albanian (word-initially before an originally stressed vowel) and lost in Anatolian is not as well-accepted but also not particularly fringe. This would of course require us to accept that *h₄ at least remained in Proto-Indo-European. In a similar vein, Kummel has suggested some initial /x/ in Western Iranian may directly continue *h₂.
Willi & Kortlandt have also offered explanations of the Greek k-aorist (and in Willi's case, also the k-perfect) that have it reflecting an original laryngeal. In Willi's case the *k was originally inserted between a laryngeal in the stem and another in (some of the) middle endings before being generalised to the whole paradigm, whilst in Kortlandt's case it is a direct reflex of a laryngeal before the word-final *-t of the 3rd person active singular again being generalised to the entire paradigm. In both cases this is not seen in all branches, although this could be justified by saying the effect was limited only to certain forms in Proto-Indo-European and either extended or hidden by analogy in later branches, without necessarily having to invoke explicit laryngeals.
Lastly there are numerous borrowings into Uralic and Finnic. If we tried to explain these as borrowings from Pre-Proto-Indo-European we'd need to have an implausibly recent date for it, or an implausibly distant date for Proto-Finnic (or both).

So no, non-laryngeal forms of Proto-Indo-European cannot explain the non-Anatolian data and we must accept that, even after Anatolian branched off the laryngeals were still preserved as distinct consonants (in at least some environments).

Another example is laryngeal breaking, whereby the sequences *iH and *uH become *ī and *ū everywhere in most branches, but in Greek shows a similar tripartite development in unstressed syllables, becoming *ie/*ia/*io and *ue/*ua/*uo (with further subsequent changes). Though that may be subsumable under the schwa indogermanica if we assume that *ə₁₂₃ goes back to *ₔH with a brief prop vowel in syllabic position, and *iH/*uH simply developed a similar prop vowel when unstressed.

Is it really a non-laryngeal reconstruction if you just call them *ə₁ ₂ ₃ instead of *h₁ ₂ ₃ though? You're still reconstructing three different proto-phonemes in that position.

@Draconis there'd be no consonantal allophone though, they'd just be vowels. From a laryngeal perspective we can of course recognise them as the syllabic allophones of the laryngeals they can absolutely be reconstructed independently. Regardless, the triple reflex of the syllabic resonants is the key point, as it cannot be sidestepped by splitting our single Schwa Indogermanicum into three and requires either an implausible system of long syllabic resonants or that we include consonantal segments that are lost in all (non-Anatolian) branches

@JanusBahsJacquet I thought about including this (and also the "epenthetic vowels" of Greek, as they used to be called), but decided that, whilst they are found in branches other than Greek, the argument (and non-laryngeal counterargument) essentially runs the same and so there was not a huge benefit to including them

Well, it depends what you mean by "fully explain".
Clearly, Ancient Greek, Classical Sanskrit, and so on can all be explained without resorting to the laryngeals. There are some words that are clearly related to each other, but their connection can't really be explained within Greek itself; you just have to say "that's the way it is". Ancient Greek scholars learned and spoke their language just fine without any conception of laryngeals.
Adding laryngeals lets us explain more of these connections. We can explain the connections between certain verb forms by positing "ablaut", for example, and the irregularities in those connections happen because some of those verbs had "laryngeals" that affect their ablaut patterns. When we see vowels becoming unexpectedly long, we can say there's an *h₁ after them, and when we see /e/ turning unexpectedly into /a/, we can say there's an *h₂ there, and so on—and where these *h₁s and *h₂s and *h₃s appear ends up being extremely consistent. If we posited an *h₂ in one form of a verb, we'll see the effects of that *h₂ in all its other forms as well.
(If you want a specific example, I can dig up the slides I use to justify the laryngeal theory with Greek data, but formatting tables on StackExchange is a pain so I haven't yet.)
Which is why the laryngeal theory has caught on! But you can also explain that data by just saying "it is what it is, these are exceptions that can't be explicated any further", which is in essence what non-laryngeal reconstructions have to do.
And, well…there's still data that the laryngeal theory has to say "it is what it is" about. There are PIE roots that look similar and have similar meanings, but we can't explain how they're related to each other with our current understanding. No theory can ever explain all the data perfectly; there was always an earlier form of the language, and there are always fossilized forms showing hints of patterns from it.

You mean "Vedic Sanskrit" above, right?  I remember reading that the Sanskrit verb classes can be regularized by positing lost laryngeals (punexti > Punati "purifies") that have disappeared @draconis

@SK Vedic arguably shows some direct reflexes of the laryngeals in specific environments, so I said Classical in the answer to avoid that concern. But Vedic does show it a lot more clearly.

Regarding table formatting, I find this ASCII table generator extremely useful. You can copy-paste tabular data (such as CSV or Excel data) into the field at the top, choose Github Markdown  for the output style and then click Parse to generate code you just paste into your answer here. Nearly always works flawlessly.

You can use any AI to ask it to format any table you want. For instance, Claude-3 Sonnet, which is free.

For a specific example, here's some data from Ancient Greek. (Not every verb has every form here, so each column is actually a mix of forms coming from the specified stem—that's why the endings vary so much.)



Present
Perfect
Aorist
Gloss




petesthai
potē
ptesthai
‘fly’


leipein
leloipa
lipein
‘leave’


pheugein
–
phugein
‘flee’


derkesthai
dedorka
drakein
‘see’


pelesthai
polos
plesthai
‘become’


genos
gonos
gignesthai
‘birth’


tithēmi
thōmos
thetos
‘place’


histāmi
stōmix
statos
‘stand’


didōmi
dōron
dotos
‘give’



For the first six rows, there's a clear pattern here. Each stem consists of two groups of consonants (e.g. p and t for 'fly'); in the present, there's an e between them, in the perfect, there's an o, and in the aorist, there's nothing. So you get the stems pet-, pot-, and pt-. There are a couple of little irregularities, like the form *drkein not being allowed (so we get drakein instead), but it's easy to see what's going on with them.
But how can we explain the last three rows? In a non-laryngeal model, we just have to admit them as irregularities. Which isn't necessarily a fatal flaw; the Ancient Greeks had no idea what laryngeals were, and still used their language just fine.
But if we introduce three new symbols, perhaps E, A, and O, then we can explain that data just the same as we explain the rest of it! In the first column we see eE, eA, eO, in the second column we see oE, oA, oO, and in the third column we see simply E, A, O on their own. This was one of the primary reasons for Saussure to propose his "coéfficients sonantiques", which we now instead call *h₁, *h₂, *h₃.
The real benefit, of course, isn't just explaining this data; it's explaining a lot of data across many different branches. But this is one specific dataset that can't really be explained without adding laryngeals, and in fact adding at least three of them.

The column headings don't match the table very well -- it would be better to use "e-grade" etc.
